# How to add snapchat Pixel on Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, facebook-pixel

I'm wondering How can I do to use snapchat pixel on a next.js
is it the same way as add [facebook pixel](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-facebook-pixel)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To integrate snapchat pixel,

- you could either follow the [official documentation](https://businesshelp.snapchat.com/s/article/pixel-direct-implementation?language=en_US) and copy paste the generated code within your app directly (using [`next/head`](https://frontend-digest.com/how-to-import-third-party-scripts-into-nextjs-d2f353a6226f)).
- An alternate way would be to use the package [**next-snapchat-pixel**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-snapchat-pixel).

```bash
# install the package
npm i next-snapchat-pixel
```

Then use it like this

```js
import SnapPixel from 'next-snapchat-pixel';

SnapPixel.init('YOUR_PIXEL_ID');

SnapPixel.track('TRACK_TYPE');

// For tracking with data (price,currency,...)
SnapPixel.trackWithData('TRACK_TYPE', {DATA})
```

[Source code](https://github.com/mirzayevkamal/next-snapchat-pixel)